# Удаление повторяющихся символов в начале строки

Tags: delphi, строки

Удаляю все точки в конце строки вот таким способом

```
while s[Length(s)] = '.' do
Delete(s, Length(s), 1);
```

**Вопрос:** А как удалить все точки в начале строки.

Простой пример:

```
....text
..text
.text
```

После удаления получаем результат

```
text
text
text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С появлением классов помощников для строк, в Delphi XE3, появился метод `TStringHelper.TrimStart()`, который позже был переименован в `TrimLeft()`, принимающие массивы символов, которые следует удалить.

```
s := s.TrimLeft(['.']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Все, вроде бы разобрался. Получается правильный ответ на вопрос:

```
while s[1] = '.' do
  Delete(s, 1, 1);
```

Comment: `while Length(s) > 0 and s[1] = '.' do`

Comment: @Igor, Получается у меня только со скобками работает. Так правильно я отредактировал или ?: while (Length(s) > 0) and (s[1] = '.') do

Comment: это у вас с учетом, что строги 1-индексированные